# Use check-bind.sh to monitor DNS Server

Tags: domain-name-system, monitoring, nagios, performance-monitoring

I want to monitor two DNS Server with Nagios and Check the DNS performances.
I have found a check_bind.sh plugin with Nagios in : https://exchange.nagios.org/directory/Plugins/Network-Protocols/DNS/check_bind-2Esh/details
But I'm really  beginner with Nagios. Should I install this plugin on my DNS server and use another plugin to send the information to Nagios ? Or what does `-p/--path-pid` mean in this command :

```
check_bind.sh -p/--path_pid /var/run/named -n/--name_pid named.pid
-r/--path-rndc /usr/sbin -s/--path-stats /var/bind -V/--bind-version 9.3/9.4/9.5 -N
```

Thanks in advance for every help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the documentation from the plugin it needs to run in the server where `bind` is running.

> check_bind.sh is a Nagios plugin to check the bind daemon whether it's running via its pid file and then gets the statistics via rndc stats. The user that run the script needs the ability to 'sudo rndc stats'!

One way to use it from your Nagios monitor would be to use `nrpe`. To achieve that you will need to configure the NRPE server in your `bind` server and then configure Nagios to use it. A sample description (CentOS based) can be found in http://xmodulo.com/nagios-remote-plugin-executor-nrpe-linux.html